# Could I load text into html during page load

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web, template-engine

I was wondering whether there was any way to load additional files during the loading of a web page. I'm trying to integrate a JavaScript templating engine into my site and would like to keep my templates in external files, and not have to load those templates asynchronously but instead to specify the required templates somewhere in the page and use their contents(which would have been loaded along with the web page) within JavaScript.
Is there any means of achieving such a functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading additional HTML files synchronously along the document is difficult. if not impossible. You would have to load javascript files that return an HTML string, or possibly use frames.

But many templating languages lets you define templates directly in the HTML code, f.ex Handlebars:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    template content
</script>
```

You can also use Node or other backend languages to pull templates from a directory and create a global Template object that contains all template strings.

When I develop using front end templates, I use separate template files and Ajax when developing, then we have a node.js script that pulls all templates and places them in a global object instead inside the main HTML request, for faster access.

Comment: Yes, I feared that would be the case(not being able to load additional files synchronously). Still, your approach to loading a bundle of templates with Ajax is reasonable so I'll go with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into `JSONP` which would allow you to include them as scripts which sounds more like what you want:

```
// HTML
<script>
    var files = [];
    var cache = function(data) {
        files.push(data);
    });
</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
// External File
cache("<content>")
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Matt. I'll definitely look into this technology, but for now I'll go with David's approach since I at least have a means of loading everything right after page load, albeit not asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in a line or two with jquery-ajax

---

Load a full file with .load http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

---

or .html http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: The OP stated "not have to load those templates asynchronously".

Answer (score 0):

```
.html()
```

This method is not available on XML documents.

In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned. Consider this code:

```
$('div.demo-container').html();
```

In order for the following 's content to be retrieved, it would have to be the first one with class="demo-container" in the document:

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
```

The result would look like this:

```
<div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
```

This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

[More Help](http://api.jquery.com/html/)